# Making a permutations function more efficient

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, performance, permutation

I'm solving a code wars kata problem but am struggling to figure out how to make my function more efficient because I keep getting stuck on the test cases that involve large numbers.

The instructions for the kata are as follows:

> Create a function that takes a positive integer and returns the next
>   bigger number that can be formed by rearranging its digits. For
>   example:
>
> ```
> 12 ==> 21
> 513 ==> 531
> 2017 ==> 2071
> nextBigger(num: 12)   // returns 21
> nextBigger(num: 513)  // returns 531
> nextBigger(num: 2017) // returns 2071
> ```
>
> If the digits can't be rearranged to form a bigger number, return -1
>   (or nil in Swift):
>
> ```
> 9 ==> -1
> 111 ==> -1
> 531 ==> -1
> ```

(I'm pretty sure) my code is bug free and the only problem it has is its efficiency:

```
from itertools import permutations

def next_bigger(n):
    possible_nums = [int(''.join(p)) for p in permutations(str(n))]
    possible_nums = list(dict.fromkeys(possible_nums))
    print(possible_nums)
    if possible_nums.index(n)+1 == len(possible_nums):
        return -1
    else:
        return possible_nums[possible_nums.index(n)+1]
```

I don't know if the `permutation()` function is whats causing the issue or the `list(dict.fromkeys(possible_nums))` but I can't seem to find a more efficient way to find each permutation of the number, `n`. Any help on whether I should restructure the entire function or just replace some bits of code to make it more efficient is much appreciated!

Comment: If your code works without any problem, please ask at [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Asocia Okay, thanks for letting me know!

Comment: This may be better suited to Code Review, but it is definitely not "opinion based" on Stack Overflow, so I'm voting to reopen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a well-known problem: how to get next lexicographical permutation.

The problem in your algorithm is that you generate all possible permutations `(O(m!) where m = len(n))` and also process each permutation with `list(dict.fromkeys(possible_nums))` creating some dictionary so overall I think is O(m * m!) (I haven't looked what you're trying to do with the dictionaries so I'm not sure if this is the exact complexity but due to permutations it is for sure at least of `O(m!)`. There is no way this would work for large inputs-i.e many digits number, instead I describe a way that we could skip generating permutations!!!

The below greedy algorithm-implementation is only O(m), m = len(n).

The following answer is based on this [link](https://www.nayuki.io/page/next-lexicographical-permutation-algorithm) where you can find a nice explanation and sample code.

Lets say that the number we want to compute is: `125330`

The algorithm:

```
1) Find longest non increasing suffix. In our case 5330 is the suffix.
2) Identify pivot i.e the next element after the suffix, here pivot is 2
3) Find rightmost successor to pivot in the suffix, i.e the number in the
   suffix that is greater than pivot, in our example rightmost occurrence of
   number 3 in 5330 is greater than pivot=2.  
4) Swap with pivot, so the number now: 135320
5) Reverse the suffix to get the next smallest permutation: 130235
```

---

Example code:

```
def next_permutation(num):
    # Find non-increasing suffix
    arr = list(str(num))
    i = len(arr) - 1
    while i > 0 and arr[i - 1] >= arr[i]:
        i -= 1
    if i <= 0:
        return -1

    # Find successor to pivot
    j = len(arr) - 1
    while arr[j] <= arr[i - 1]:
        j -= 1
    arr[i - 1], arr[j] = arr[j], arr[i - 1]

    # Reverse suffix
    arr[i : ] = arr[len(arr) - 1 : i - 1 : -1]
    return int("".join(arr))
```

---

Test cases:

```
In: 12 Out: 21
In: 513 Out: 531
In: 2017 Out: 2071
In: 9 Out: -1
In: 111 Out: -1
In: 531 Out: -1
In: 144 Out: 414
```